# How may I create custom keyframe css animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, css, keyframe

I need to create and run custom css3 animation with javascript.
When I need to create transition I write something like this:

```
element.style[Modernizr.prefixed('transform')] = 'rotateY(50deg)';
```

When I need animate element I should write

```
element.style[Modernizr.prefixed('animation')] = "'test' 2s ease-out infinite";
```

But I can't create keyframe for 'open' in the same way.
Sure, I may write something like

```
document.creteElement("style").innerHTML = rule;
```

but this is dirty idea, so after reading [programmatically changing webkit-transformation values in animation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105530/programmatically-changing-webkit-transformation-values-in-animation-rules) I write this:

```
var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("style")),
index = Modernizr._prefixes.length,
rule = "";

while(index--){
    rule+="@"+Modernizr._prefixes[index]+"keyframes 'test'{ 0%{opacity:1;} 50%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}} ";
}

style.sheet.insertRule(rule);
$(".mojo")[0].style[Modernizr.prefixed('animation')] = "'test' 2s ease-out infinite";
```

​

and get error: Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

What I am doing wrong and how may I do this more appropriate way? This look horrible.

http://jsfiddle.net/silentimp/273e2/ — test

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/silentimp/273e2/1/ — solution

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I'd like to see it taken further, maybe abstracted into a function that allowed you easy access to your `CSSKeyframeRules` in a way that allowed for get/set on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keyframes = "@-webkit-keyframes{...}";
var s = document.createElement( 'style' );
s.innerHTML = keyframes;
```

[source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/09/detecting-and-generating-css-animations-in-javascript/)

or

https://github.com/krazyjakee/jQuery-Keyframes

Comment: Got the error like: `Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
file:///Users/ks/Desktop/website/undefined`