# Chrome Suddenly Stopped Accepting insertRule()

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have an HTML5 game that has been running beautifully for weeks.

Suddenly, about an hour ago, it will no longer run in Chrome.  I narrowed the issue down to a JavaScript error that occurs only in Chrome.

I have isolated said code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/quM3L/

...the error is produced on line 4:

```
var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
var rule =  "score_10_typing {from {width: 0} to {width: 11em}}";
if (CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // W3C
    style.sheet.insertRule("@keyframes " + rule, 0);
}
else if (CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // WebKit
    style.sheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes " + rule, 0);
}
else if (CSSRule.MOZ_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // Mozilla
    style.sheet.insertRule("@-moz-keyframes " + rule, 0);
}
```

...that runs just fine in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari, etc.

It ran fine in Chrome until an hour ago.  (Tested on multiple computers.)

Does anyone have an idea of how to perhaps get around this?  Chrome must have just today updated their JS engine to not support [CSSStyleSHeet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule), I suppose.

Thanks in advance for any help.

([The original game is located here.](http://arcadejhs.github.io/HTML5-Space-Invaders/)  As you can see, it runs fine in all browsers other than Chrome.)

Comment: If it happened an hour ago, we're probably as wise as you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fair enough.  A guy can hope, though, right?  :)  Also, I wanted to post this in case anyone else searches for the issue - so they can see they're not alone.

Comment: Coders are never alone. We stand together on the shoulders of giants. Also, we all go to the same conventions...

Comment: Thanx Leng, I am the author of the original code (http://arcadejhs.github.io/HTML5-Space-Invaders/): I quickly solved the issue thanks to your question :-D

Comment: @Matteo Hey again Matteo!  This is Jacob, we exchanged a couple emails and you pulled my bug fix for the aliens getting stuck on the side of the screen.  Awesome!  I was going to submit another pull request, but looks like you beat me to it.  Haha, good work.  :)

Comment: Hey Jacob! Nice to hear from you! Yesterday night I worked a little bit again on the game, and found this bug! Then I found your question on Stackoverflow, which actually saved me a lot of time in solving it! You really are the major contributor to the project! Ahah :) Thanx!

Comment: I will push more bug fixes later. Check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, evidently, Chrome was falling into the first if statement (W3C) instead of into the 3rd (Webkit).  So, they must have just updated their engine today to have both `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE` **and** `CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE` (thanks Ithcy).  What a pain.

Reorder the `if` statement, and the code runs fine [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhjq/):

```
var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
var rule =  "score_10_typing {from {width: 0} to {width: 11em}}";
if (CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // WebKit
    style.sheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes " + rule, 0);
}
else if (CSSRule.MOZ_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // Mozilla
    style.sheet.insertRule("@-moz-keyframes " + rule, 0);
}
else if (CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // W3C
    style.sheet.insertRule("@keyframes " + rule, 0);
}
```

This is not good, because Chrome doesn't accept `@keyframes`, but it does accept `@-webkit-keyframes`.  So why they have changed their engine to also include `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE` is beyond me.

Comment: both `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE` and `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE`? You don't say... :)

Answer (score 0):

`CSSStyleSHeet.insertRule()` is still supported, as you'll see if you try to insert something simple like `"body { color: blue; }"`. It's the `@keyframes` thing. Try `@-webkit-keyframes` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't Chrome be jumping into the first `if else()` instead of going into the first `if()`?  Why is it not going into the //Webkit commented code?  Also, please see my updated code in the question.  Forgot to include the actual insertRules

Comment: That I don't know. You've changed your question since I answered.

Comment: because Chrome (edit: Chrome 31) has both `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE` and `CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE`?

Comment: @Amadan from my Chrome 31 just now: `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE //7` `CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE //7`

Comment: @ithcy: Ah, there we go. I'm still on 30, and the former is `undefined`. If the OP's Chrome got updated in the last hour or so, mystery solved.

Comment: @ithcy You're correct, that was the issue.  Chrome just updated to have both `CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE` **and** `CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE` about two hours ago.

Comment: @Amadan And you're correct as well, it was my Chrome silently updating.