# Javascript : creating a 'class' dynamically and adding property value to it....is it possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a question , is it possible to add property/value to a class created dynamically?

for Ex:

```
var clss=document.createAttribute('class');

// here can we add property/value to a "clss " like

// clss.someMethod('width' , '100px');

// clss.someMethod('border' , '2px solid red');

// something like this...is it possible ??

div.setAttribute('class' , cls);
```

I know how to add inline-style , i just want to add it "clss" , is it possible?
 Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: No, that's not how class attribute works. You can create a `style` element instead.

Comment: @Vohuman  Not possible?

Comment: Don't you want to use "style" and not "class"?

Comment: @epascarello If i use style , that would again be inline rite , if i am not wrong :(

Comment: Just saying your example shows styles and you are setting a class. If you want to do something like you want to do, you would need to code a method yourself.

Comment: Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105530/programmatically-changing-webkit-transformation-values-in-animation-rules

Comment: @epascarello pls can u just show me how to do it , it will be very helpfull. I am learning javascript , and i donno from where this idea came in my mind , still a beginner :)

Comment: @joews that did help me a bit , though i dint get it fully . thank you (y)