# ASP.NET AJAX--styleSheet.insertRule() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

My application generates animations dynamically in server code.  For the element to be animated, I apply the animation styles in-line, like so (the element IDs are GUIDs with a letter prefix to prevent collision):

```
<div class="ScrollingDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 27px;">
    <p id="p9a6960428d594935b2540b1f8466f47a" style="animation:scroll-p9a6960428d594935b2540b1f8466f47a 10s linear infinite; width: 131px; height: 27px; transform: translateX(640px); -moz-transform: translateX(640px); -webkit-transform: translateX(640px); -moz-animation: scroll-p9a6960428d594935b2540b1f8466f47a 10s linear infinite; -webkit-animation: scroll-p9a6960428d594935b2540b1f8466f47a 10s linear infinite;">
        This is a test
    </p>
</div>
```

and assign that as the `InnerHtml` of the container.  I also generate on the server side the keyframes, like so:

```
@keyframes scroll-p9a6960428d594935b2540b1f8466f47a { 0% { transform: translateX(640px); } 100% { transform: translateX(-131px); } }
```

and put them in a hidden field on the form for the client to add to the style sheet using Eli Grey's approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105530/programmatically-changing-webkit-transformation-values-in-animation-rules) post.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    var oStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    oStyleSheet.insertRule(rule, oStyleSheet.cssRules.length);
}
```

I've verified that the style and rules are working in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3v40hx6/) but it's not working when I add them programmatically.  I can watch in the debugger that `oStyleSheet` is getting a new entry in its `cssRules` property.  Any ideas as to either a) why it's not working or b) (better yet) how I can debug this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read all the way to the bottom of the answer I cited.  Turns out that you have to stop then restart the animation for changes to the style sheet to take effect.